# Why do you need to remove the HDD to clean install the OS on the SSD?

Tags: ssd, windows-installation, clean-install

It seems that most sources advise to only have one drive (in general the SSD) plugged into the motherboard when clean installing an OS (in particular Windows).

Why is it so? What could go wrong when clean installing it with both an HDD and SSD plugged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "second" drive is a boot drive, and with the same license, it can go wrong for this reason as well. For simplicity I remove all but one drive to get started.  If you have a plain (non-boot) data drive as drive 2, it can stay there without issue

Comment: Ok so if it is a brand new computer that has just been built but with no OS on no drive there is no point removing it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that will work as there is nothing to conflct

Answer (score 2):

From [setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition/#Causes_of_this_error](https://neosmart.net/wiki/setup-was-unable-to-create-a-new-system-partition/#Causes_of_this_error)

> Depending on how your PC is configured and which hardware you are
>   using, Windows setup can sometimes be unable to tell which drive is an
>   external USB drive and which drive is a local disk that Windows should
>   be installed to. This especially happens when using larger USB drives
>   to install Windows or if you have configured your BIOS to boot from
>   the USB drive first always.
>
> If Windows setup cannot reliably determine which is the boot drive,
>   this error will appear.
>
> During setup, Windows must identify which drive is your primary boot
>   drive in order to correctly configure the MBR and bootloader. This
>   error does not normally apply to EFI and UEFI installations of Windows
>   7, Windows 8, or Windows 10.

Comment: Not sure to fully understand the link between my question and this answer: can this error happen when installing windows on a brand new computer that has no OS installed on no drive?